# How to use Inception v3 in Tensorflow

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision

I am trying to import Inception v3 in TensorFlow. I wish to apply it after reading [this tutorial on object detection](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keras, now fully merged with the new TensorFlow 2.0, allows you to call a long list of pre-trained models. If you want to create an Inception V3, you do:

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import InceptionV3
```

That `InceptionV3` you just imported is not a model itself, it's a class. You now need to instantiate an `InceptionV3` object, with:

```
my_model = InceptionV3()
```

at this point, `my_model` is a Keras `Sequential()` model with the architecture and trained weights of Inception V3, that you can re-train, freeze, save, and load as you need.

Check also the [full list of models available](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications) in the module, it's great.

Comment: Does this apply with docker as well

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have practical experience with Docker. However, since the GCP is configured for using containers, I think it can be applied without problems